# People + their + singular noun

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:

“With passionate justifications to support their view, many people believe that negative consequences have arisen as a direct result of computers in the classroom.”

Does view work, or should it be “views” ...?

Answer (score 1):

View, singular. Many people share one single view, namely that negative consequences have arisen as a direct result of computers in the classroom.